# os.environ.get() cannot find the variables, might be path related?

Tags: python, operating-system

Edit: fixed typo, now I get a new error. It does run, but when I try to load the page I get an error instead.

So here is the code in

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ.get('SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI')
```

Here is the variable in my .bash_profile file:

```
export SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI='sqlite:///site.db'
```

Here is the error

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'drivername'
```

I have a .bash_profile file in home, in flask_blog_test in flaskblog and in the venv directory with the variable. But nothing works.

When I os.environ.get('PATH') in my config.py file I get the following:

```
/home/my_pc/running_python_projects/flask_blog_test/venv/bin:/home/my_pc/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

When I try to print the variable I obviously get nothing. Anyway to fix this?

Comment: Replace `-` with `=`...

Comment: Oh yeah :( good one. It still does not work though. It runs but it can still not find the variable.

Comment: `print(os.environ)` to see what's actually in your environment if you get a None..

Comment: Could you do an export manually and run the script once  and see ?

Comment: A bunch of stuff but not the variables I put in my .bash_profile file

Comment: And see this [why my .bash_profile is not getting sourced](https://askubuntu.com/questions/121073/why-bash-profile-is-not-getting-sourced-when-opening-a-terminal)

Comment: Yes that fixed it, thank you

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted is not the code that's actually running:

```py
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ.get('SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI')
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI - os.environ.get('SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI')
#                       ^
```

Replace the `-` with a `=`.